# How can I cron Let's Encrypt certificate renewal?

Tags: lets-encrypt

At present, `letsencrypt-auto`, when run from the command line with e.g. `-d example.com -d www.example.com` for arguments, requests interactively whether I want HTTP requests forcibly redirected to HTTPS.

How can I cron this? Can I run it `< input.txt` or some form of `yes 2 |`? Or does `letsencrypt-auto` act differently when it's not attached to a tty?

Thanks,

Comment: You probably just want `letsencrypt renew` or `certbot renew` - once configured you no longer need to do the autoconfig of the webserver.  Then again, I only use LE to obtain the certs, I did the webserver config myself...

Answer (score 4):

First, update to the latest version of `certbot`. If you are still calling `letsencrypt-auto` then you likely have a very old version that will stop working sooner or later.

All you need to do to renew is call `certbot-auto renew` or `certbot renew`. Each cert you have obtained already has its own configuration file stored in `/etc/letsencrypt` and doesn't need options explicitly specified again.

Ideally you should be using a `certbot` package provided by your Linux distribution. In addition to remaining up to date, these include a systemd timer which you can enable to have the renewal job run automatically.